# jQuery.ajax is replacing "?" in url with jquery's version number

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter, cross-domain

Attempting a cross-domain JSON exchange with jQuery's ajax (also, getJSON).

jQuery is replacing the "callback=?" with "callback=jQuery181051499094045721_1355119986411"...

Here is the Specific URL:
http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&callback=?&include_entities=true

jQuery makes this request:

http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&callback=jQuery181051499094045721_1355119986411&include_entities=true&_=1355119986471

Answer (score 1):

This is how jquery handles [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  The callback function is dynamically generated.